# nodejs: Is calling functions from require's cache as fast as functions in global scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, caching, require

Suppose I have a file called external.js:

```
// external.js

//define a print function and make it public
module.exports.print = function(text) {
    console.log(text)
}
```

And then I have a file called main.js:

```
// main.js

// call require('./external.js').print so that it'll be in the require's cache
require('./external.js').print('I am now in the cache')

// and define a function equivalent to print in the global scope
function localPrint(text) {
    console.log(text)
}

// Finally, define two functions which use the localPrint and the print in external.js
function echo1(text) {
    require('./external.js').print(text)
}

function echo2(text) {
    localPrint(text)
}
```

Will there be any difference in performance between echo1 and echo2?
I dare say there will be not. Accessing a global function should be as fast as a function in the require's cache. What do you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will there be any difference in performance between echo1 and echo2?

Perhaps a trivially small one, yes. `echo1` makes an unnecessary function call (at *least* one, `require` probably makes several others) and an unnecessary property lookup (on the object returned) (and again, at *least* one; `require` probably has to do a couple of property lookups to find your resource in cache).

Whether it *matters* is another question entirely.

I'd probably do this:

```
var print = require('./external.js').print;
```

Or if you really prefer another name:

```
var echo = require('./external.js').print;
```

Or if there's a reason for wrapping the call:

```
var print = require('./external.js').print;
function echo(text) {
    print(text);
}
```

Comment: Will doing like you suggest create a copy of the require('./external.js).print function in the main.js global scope? I guess so because if I clear the cache I still have access to that function. Doing this way localPrint and print(as defined by you) are basically the same?

Comment: Hello, you are entirely right! Using the require once is much better if we want to use the object multiple times.

Comment: @Core_dumped: Not a **copy**, no; a *reference*. Clearing the cache doesn't affect it because you have that outstanding reference, keeping the one copy of the function in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the benchmark :

main.js

```
// main.js

// call require('./external.js').print so that it'll be in the require's cache
var e = require('./external.js');

// and define a function equivalent to print in the global scope
function localPrint() {
    var hello = "hello";
    return hello;
}

var f = {
  hello : function(){
    var hello = "hello";
    return hello;
  }
}

// Finally, define two functions which use the localPrint and the print in external.js
function echo1() {
    e.hello();
}


function echo2() {
    localPrint()
}

function echo3(){
  f.hello();
}

(function (){
  var times = 100000000;
  var start1 = +new Date();
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    echo1('text');
  };
  var stop1 = +new Date();

  var start2 = +new Date();
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    echo2('text');
  };
  var stop2 = +new Date();

  var start3 = +new Date();
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    echo3('text');
  };
  var stop3 = +new Date();

  console.log('From require', stop1,start1, stop1 - start1);
  console.log('From local', stop2,start2, stop2 - start2);
  console.log('From object', stop3,start3, stop3 - start3);
})();
```

external.js

```
// external.js
//define a print function and make it public
module.exports.hello = function() {
    var hello = "hello";
    return hello;
}
```

result :

```
From require 1430050276387 1430050276313 74
From local 1430050276460 1430050276387 73
From object 1430050277569 1430050276460 1109
```

The difference for 100M calls each is not significant from the require or for a local variable (73 & 74 ms). BUT, from an object is 15 times slower (1109 ms) than using a require...

Use the powerful module system of NodeJS instead of creating big objects.

Hope it helps & I hope it is correct!